# Question about product of compact sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am reading the proof of the fact that the cartesion product of two compact sets is compact. But I ran into the following question.

> Let $A$ and $B$ be compact sets in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and
> $\{O_\lambda\}_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ be an open cover of $A \times B$.
> For each $(a,b) \in A \times B$, we can choose some $\lambda =
>  \lambda(a,b)$ such that $(a,b) \in O_{\lambda(a,b)}$. By construction,
> $O_{\lambda(a,b)}$ is open, hence the point $(a,b)$ is contained in
> some open box $X \subset O_{\lambda(a,b)}$ where $X = U_{(a,b)} \times
>  V_{(a,b)}$, where $U_{(a,b)} \subset A$ and $V_{(a,b)} \subset B$.

**Question:** I am little confused. How do we know that $U_{(a,b)} \subset A$ and $V_{(a,b)} \subset B$?

I am not asking about the whole proof. Just want to clarify that moment. Please do not duplicate it.

Comment: The author must mean that $U_{(a,b)}$ and $V_{(a,b)}$ are relatively open subsets of $A$ and $B,$ respectively. How do you define an open set in the product? Isn't it a union of basic open sets? What are the basic open sets in the product, aren't they exactly boxes?

Comment: In a comment to a posted answer you say that: open set in $\mathbb R^d$ is the set such that any point of this set has some nbhd inside this set. Ok, what is a neighborhood, there are different definitions, which one do you use?

Comment: @Mirko, for $x\in \mathbb{R}^d$, the set $N_{\epsilon}(x):=\{y\in \mathbb{R}^d: \lVert y-x\rVert_2<\epsilon\}$ is $\epsilon$-nbd of $x$, where by $\lVert \rVert_2$ I mean euclidean distance in $\mathbb{R}^d$

Answer (score 0):

$X$ is a box.  A box is a product of open sets in $A$ and $B$ respectively. The definition of being open in the product implies the existence of just such a box.  Note the product topology is the box topology in the case of a finite product.

That's we're checking for compactness in the product/ box topology.   That's the topology generated by boxes (products of open sets in $A$ and $B$).

Edit:   The product topology on $\Bbb R^{2d}=\Bbb R^d×\Bbb R^d$ is nothing but the standard Euclidean topology. They coincide.  I know I said "topology" again,  and you don't want that,  but my point is just that open sets in $\Bbb R^{2d}$ are all unions of cross products $U×V$, where $U,V\subset \Bbb R^d$.  I'm afraid though that to get $U\subset A,V\subset B$, you may have to consider $A,B$ as subspaces (and here comes that word again).  See compactness is a topological notion.   But relax, you're already familiar with the one on $\Bbb R^n$.  In fact that's probably the prototype.

Comment: Sorry but I did not get your reasoning! How does it answe my question?

Comment: Here $X$ is an open box and hence $X=U_{(a,b)}\times V_{(a,b)}$, where $U_{(a,b)}, V_{(a,b)}$ are open sets in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Why it should be an open set in $A$ and $B$? I don't think that your answer explains my questions.

Comment: Well,  you didn't mention that you were in $\Bbb R^d$.  But nevertheless $A$ and $B$ as subsets of Euclidean space are topological spaces in their own right.   If it isn't the product topology we're considering,  then what could it be?  No it's clearly the product topology.   And that means every open set is a union of boxes.  Where a box is a product of an open set in $A$ with one in $B$.

Comment: this is a problem from real analysis. We did not discuss topology yet. So it should be proved from first principles. I was wondering can you show the complete proof please?

Comment: Sorry I missed $\Bbb R^d$.

Comment: If you can upload the proof tht would be really great! And I'll appreciate it! Most proof which I see here they are based on the notion of topology.

Comment: Well now I suppose you use compactness of $A$ and $B$.  Then you have two finite subcovers.  Then the boxes formed from those subcovers provide a finite subcover of $A×B$.  That's my guess.   It's just that if $A,B\subset\Bbb R^d$, then isn't $A×B\subset\Bbb R^{2d}$?

Comment: Yes, $A\times B\subset \mathbb{R}^{2d}$

Comment: @RFZ It is not clear what you mean by "first principles". These are not a substitute for precise definitions, and if the proof here is topological you better discuss some topology in your real analysis class. Else, you need to clarify in your question what is your definition of open sets - in the product and in the factors - so then someone could think of an appropriate answer.

Comment: @Mirko, open set in $\mathbb{R}^d$ is the set such that any point of this set has some nbhd inside this set.

Answer (score 0):

Ok (too long for a comment, but I read your definition of a neighborhood) then do a picture for the plane first as it is easier to visualize (so $d=1$). A neighborhood of a point $p=(a,b)$ is a circle (or rather, an open disk) centered at $p.$ You can inscribe a square in this circle, with horizontal and vertical sides. This square is the product $I\times J$ of two open intervals $I$ and $J$ (each a subset of the respective factor), think $I$ is like the set $U_{(a,b)}$, and $J$ is like the set $V_{(a,b)}$ that the author uses. Except, in the "relative topology" (even if you may not have discussed topology), these neighborhoods you work with are intersected with the sets under consideration, e.g. each $O_\lambda$ is the intersection with $A\times B$ of some set $M_\lambda$ open in the product (or real lines), while $U_{(a,b)}$ and $V_{(a,b)}$ are the intersections with $A$ and $B$ respectively or some open sets $P$ and $Q$ in the respective factor.